# RequireJS: Define a module - TypeError: Unable to get property of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have two JavaScript files `file1.js` and `file2.js` which I want to create modules out of it to use it with RequireJS.

**file1.js**

```
define('file1', ['file2'], function(myVar) {
    console.log(myVar);

    myVar.doSomething = function() {
        return {
            'test': 13
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, there is a dependency to `file2.js` and I need to get the `myVar`. Here you can see `file2` and a code snippet what I am doing inside this file.

**file2.js**

```
define('file2', ['someOtherDep'], function(someVarFromSomeOtherDep) {
    var myVar = (function() {
        var test = someVarFromSomeOtherDep.test.a;

        var doIt = function(var1) {
            // …
            return x;
        };

        return {
            doIt: doIt
        }
    }());
    console.log(myVar);
    return myVar;
});
```

If I use `file1` as a dependency and call `myVar.doSomething()`, I get `TypeError: Unable to get property 'doSomething' of undefined or null reference` and both `console.log` shows `[object Object] {}`.

Here is the file which depends on `file1`:

```
define(['file1'], function(myVar) {
    var test = myVar.doSomething();
});
```

So, what's wrong here? It seems that `myVar` is not returned correctly from `file2`?

Comment: In your `file2.js` you're missing a closing `);` on the last line

Comment: If the syntax is not the issue, can you verify there is not a circular dependency between file1 and file2?

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, you are right, but that was only from copy/paste, in my source code it is right.

Comment: @sma: No, there is no circular dependency.

Comment: As an aside, avoid explicitly giving names to your modules if don't have a reason to do it this way. Let RequireJS deal with module naming based on your file paths.

Comment: Okay, so the first parameter of define, in my case ``file1``and ``file2`` I can throw away and then the filename is used? But changing the file name I have to change the naming of dependencies if the module is needed as a dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> both console.log shows `[object Object] {}`

That's odd. Have you tried expanding the view? You should be able to see your methods.

> I get `TypeError: Unable to get property 'doSomething' of undefined or null reference`
>   So, what's wrong here? It seems that myVar is not returned correctly from file2?

No. `myVar` is not returned correctly from file1 - in fact, nothing is returned there at all!

```
define('file1', ['file2'], function(myVar) {
    console.log(myVar);

    myVar.doSomething = function() {
        return {
            'test': 13
        }
    }
    return myVar;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

You're getting the error from the line `var test = myVar.doSomething();` (that depends on file 1), not from file 1 (that depends on file 2).

Comment: You are right, expanding the view I can see the function ``doSomething``. And yes, I did not return it here. That was the only problem here! Thank you!